# Em Python, como se explica a expressão 'x = not x'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Já sei o resultado, mas gostaria de entender o que acontece, o por que do tal resultado...

Por exemplo:

```
>>> a = True
>>> b = not a    
>>> print(b)
False
```

É uma coisa simples, mas me sinto chateado por usar algo sem saber como funciona.

Comment: Não sei se eu entendi a sua dúvida, mas respondi da maneira mais completa que pude. Se não era isso que você queria, favor esclarecer o que na expressão citada que você não entende.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! De maneira indireta a sua resposta me esclareceu a dúvida, a qual surgiu depois de ler um código que usava essa expressão, pois estava acostumado a usar o not em expressões como 'if x not in y:' ou 'if x not True:'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A precedência dos operadores `=` e `not` é tal que a instrução citada deve ser interpretada como:

```
=(b, not(a))
```

i.e. "avalie `not(a)` e guarde o resultado em `b`".

Já a expressão `not(x)` retorna `True` se `x` for falso em um contexto booleano, ou `False` se `x` for verdadeiro nesse mesmo contexto. Em Python, os seguintes valores são considerados "falsos":

```
False
None
0
0.0
-0.0
""
[]
()
{}
class MinhaClasse(object):
    def __bool__(self): # Python 3
        return False
    def __nonzero__(self): # Python 2
        return False
```

Os demais valores são considerados "verdadeiros".

Como `a` é um dos valores verdadeiros (`True`), então `not(a)` avalia pra `False`, e esse é o valor que é armazenado em `b`.

Se uma mesma variável fosse usada (tal como no título da sua pergunta), naturalmente toda a avaliação no lado direito ocorreria antes da atribuição ao lado esquerdo:

```
>>> x = True
>>> x = not x   # x é True; not(True) é False; guarde False em x => x é False.
>>> print(x)
False
```

Note que o resultado de `not(x)` sempre será `True` ou `False`, somente, ao contrário de operadores como o `and` ou o `or` que sempre retornam um dos valores originais:

```
>>> 1 and "teste"   # Verdadeiro(1) E Verdadeiro(2) é Verdadeiro(2)
'teste'
>>> {} and True     # Falso(1) E Verdadeiro(2) é Falso(1) => curto-circuito
{}
>>> False or []     # Falso(1) OU Falso(2) é Falso(2)
[]
>>> 42 or None      # Verdadeiro(1) OU Falso(2) é Verdadeiro(1) => curto-circuito
42
```